# Django form post doesn't save to DB

Tags: python, django

The form I made on Django doesn't save any data, I think it's a validation issue but I can't find where the problem is - whenever I click on the "submit" button the page is refreshed but no new entries are created - when I do that from Django Admin it works fine.

I'm a complete beginner and this is my very first Django project.

**models.py**

```
class Utente(models.Model):
    id_utente = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    gen_utente = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=GEN_CHOICES)
    age_utente = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    con_utente = CountryField()
    per_utente = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=PER_CHOICES)
    pres_utente = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=PRES_CHOICES)
    doc_utente = models.CharField(max_length=29, choices=DOC_CHOICES)
    vis_utente = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=VIS_CHOICES)
    san_utente = models.CharField(max_length=17, choices=SAN_CHOICES)
    nnb_utente = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=NNB_CHOICES)
    unnb_utente = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=UNNB_CHOICES)
    va_utente = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=VA_CHOICES)
    tem_utente = models.DateField()
    res_utente = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Utente n: {self.id_utente} del {self.tem_utente}'
```

**forms.py** *(I've removed the labels)*

```
class UtenteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Utente
        fields = ['id_utente', 'gen_utente', 'age_utente', 'con_utente', 'per_utente', 'pres_utente', 'doc_utente', 'vis_utente', 'san_utente', 'nnb_utente', 'unnb_utente', 'vac_utente', 'tem_utente', 'res_utente']
        labels = {
            'id_utente': '.......',
            'gen_utente': '.......',
            'age_utente': '.......',
            'con_utente': '.......',
            'per_utente': '.......',
            'pres_utente': '.......',
            'doc_utente': '.......',
            'vis_utente': '.......',
            'san_utente': '.......',
            'nnb_utente': '.......',
            'unnb_utente': '.......',
            'vac_utente': '.......',
            'tem_utente': '.......',
            'res_utente': '.......'
        }
        widgets = {
            'id_utente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'disabled': True}),
            'gen_utente': forms.Select(choices=SESSO_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'age_utente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'pattern': '([0-9]{2})'}),
            'con_utente': CountrySelectWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'per_utente': forms.Select(choices=PERMANENZA_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'pres_utente': forms.Select(choices=PRESENZA_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'doc_utente': forms.Select(choices=DOCUMENTI_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'vis_utente': forms.Select(choices=VISITEPREG_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'san_utente': forms.Select(choices=DOCSANITARI_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nnb_utente': forms.Select(choices=MMG_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'unnb_utente': forms.Select(choices=USOMMG_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'vac_utente': forms.Select(choices=VACCINOCOVID_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'vis_utente': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'res_utente': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows':'3'})
        }
```

**views.py**

```
# Add new utente
def aggiungi_utente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UtenteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_id_utente = form.cleaned_data ['id_utente']
            new_gen_utente = form.cleaned_data ['gen_utente']
            new_age_utente = form.cleaned_data ['age_utente']
            new_con_utente = form.cleaned_data ['con_utente']
            new_per_utente = form.cleaned_data ['per_utente']
            new_pres_utente = form.cleaned_data ['pres_utente']
            new_doc_utente = form.cleaned_data ['doc_utente']
            new_vis_utente = form.cleaned_data ['vis_utente']
            new_san_utente = form.cleaned_data ['san_utente']
            new_nnb_utente = form.cleaned_data ['nnb_utente']
            new_usnnb_utente = form.cleaned_data ['unnb_utente']
            new_vac_utente = form.cleaned_data ['vac_utente']
            new_tem_utente = form.cleaned_data ['tem_utente']
            new_res_utente = form.cleaned_data ['res_utente']


            new_utente = Utente(
                id_utente = new_id_utente,
                gen_utente = new_gen_utente,
                age_utente = new_age_utente,
                con_utente = new_con_utente,
                per_utente = new_per_utente,
                pres_utente = new_pres_utente,
                doc_utente = new_doc_utente,
                vis_utente = new_vis_utente,
                san_utente = new_san_utente,
                nnb_utente = new_nnb_utente,
                unnb_utente = new_unnb_utente,
                vac_utente = new_vac_utente,
                tem_utente = new_tem_utente,
                res_utente = new_res_utente
            )
            new_utente.save()
            return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
                'form': UtenteForm(),
                'success': True
            })
    else:
        form = UtenteForm()
    return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
        'form': UtenteForm()
    })

# Modify and edit utente
def modifica_utenti(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        utente= Utente.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = UtenteForm(request.POST, instance=utente)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'utenti/mod-utenti.html',{
                'form': form,
                'success': True
            })
    else:
        utente = Utente.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = UtenteForm(instance=utente)
    return render(request, 'utenti/mod-utenti.html', {
        'form': form
    })

# To delete utente
def delete_utente(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        utente = Utente.objects.get(pk=pk)
        utente.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('utenti'))

# View utente
def view_utente(request, pk):
    utente = Utente.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**template file**

```
{% extends "utenti/base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h3 class="text-center m-4">Add new utente</h3>
    {% if success %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Added successfully.
            <a href="{% url 'utenti' %}" class="alert-link">Go to the list.</a>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-address-card fa-lg"></i> Create utente
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{% url 'aggiungi-utenti' %}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            <a href="{% url 'utenti' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you try to render the form errors and see if it is a validation error or not? Adding `{{ form.errors }}` in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your view to output the validation errors if `is_valid()` is false. This will help you narrow it down.

- **error** outputs raw HTML
- **errors.as_data()** outputs a dictonary (might be easier to read)

```py
# Add new utente
def aggiungi_utente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UtenteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_id_utente = form.cleaned_data ['id_utente']
            new_gen_utente = form.cleaned_data ['gen_utente']
            new_age_utente = form.cleaned_data ['age_utente']
            new_con_utente = form.cleaned_data ['con_utente']
            new_per_utente = form.cleaned_data ['per_utente']
            new_pres_utente = form.cleaned_data ['pres_utente']
            new_doc_utente = form.cleaned_data ['doc_utente']
            new_vis_utente = form.cleaned_data ['vis_utente']
            new_san_utente = form.cleaned_data ['san_utente']
            new_nnb_utente = form.cleaned_data ['nnb_utente']
            new_usnnb_utente = form.cleaned_data ['unnb_utente']
            new_vac_utente = form.cleaned_data ['vac_utente']
            new_tem_utente = form.cleaned_data ['tem_utente']
            new_res_utente = form.cleaned_data ['res_utente']


            new_utente = Utente(
                id_utente = new_id_utente,
                gen_utente = new_gen_utente,
                age_utente = new_age_utente,
                con_utente = new_con_utente,
                per_utente = new_per_utente,
                pres_utente = new_pres_utente,
                doc_utente = new_doc_utente,
                vis_utente = new_vis_utente,
                san_utente = new_san_utente,
                nnb_utente = new_nnb_utente,
                unnb_utente = new_unnb_utente,
                vac_utente = new_vac_utente,
                tem_utente = new_tem_utente,
                res_utente = new_res_utente
            )
            new_utente.save()
            return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
                'form': UtenteForm(),
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            print(form.error)
            print(form.errors.as_data())
    else:
        form = UtenteForm()
    return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
        'form': UtenteForm()
    })
```

---

Also if you just do `form.save()` it'll do all that cleaned_data stuff for you:

```py
# Add new utente
def aggiungi_utente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UtenteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
                'form': UtenteForm(),
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            print(form.error)
            print(form.errors.as_data())
    else:
        form = UtenteForm()
    return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {
        'form': UtenteForm()
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the problem was the fact that I used UUID as a primary key and disabled the widget. With errors and errors.as_data() I was able to find the problem. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but I will do it as soon as I gain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is doing too much work: a Django form can perfectly handle creating an object itself:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def aggiungi_utente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UtenteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('utenti')
    else:
        form = UtenteForm()
    return render(request, 'utenti/add-utenti.html', {'form': form})
```

By passing the invalid form to the rendering function again, it will render the problem with the form.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.